# Trying to hide the title column the sharepoint way

Tags: content-type, list-definition, display-form

I am currently just messing around with defining lists via the elements.xml

**Content Type**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <!-- Parent ContentType: EmptyConentType (EmployeeManagement\EmptyContentType) (0x02) -->
  <ContentType ID="0x02002f264075a21e483da3d57561c27dd168"
              Name="EmployeeContentType"
              Group="Custom Content Types"
              Description="My Content Type"
              Inherits="TRUE"
              Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}"  Name="Title" DisplayName="Name" Required="TRUE" Sealed="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{ABD19BB1-87E8-4F9C-9809-5629F180DC82}"  Name="Surname" DisplayName="Surname" Required="TRUE" Sealed="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{596379ED-4583-4A38-B9A6-64D0FD55AB37}"  Name="Email" DisplayName="Email" Required="TRUE" Sealed="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{86811853-7E52-4515-A88D-A8FA9D450905}"  Name="ContactNumber" DisplayName="Contact Number" Required="TRUE" Sealed="TRUE"/>
    </FieldRefs>
  </ContentType>
  <!-- Surname-->
    <Field ID="{ABD19BB1-87E8-4F9C-9809-5629F180DC82}"
     Name="Surname"
     DisplayName="Surname"
     Type="Text"
     Required="FALSE"
     Group="Person Details"/>
  <!-- Email-->
    <Field ID="{596379ED-4583-4A38-B9A6-64D0FD55AB37}"
     Name="Email"
     DisplayName="Email"
     Type="Text"
     Required="FALSE"
     Group="Person Details"/>
  <!-- ContactNumber-->
    <Field ID="{86811853-7E52-4515-A88D-A8FA9D450905}"
     Name="ContactNumber"
     DisplayName="Contact Number"
     Type="Text"
     Required="FALSE"
     Group="Person Details"/>
</Elements>
```

**List Schema**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="EmployeeManagement - EmployeeRegisterDefinition" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/EmployeeManagement-EmployeeRegisterDefinition" BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <MetaData>
    <ContentTypes>
      <ContentTypeRef ID="0x02002f264075a21e483da3d57561c27dd168"></ContentTypeRef>
    </ContentTypes>
    <Fields>
    </Fields>
    <Views>
      <View BaseViewID="0" Type="HTML" MobileView="TRUE" TabularView="FALSE">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkTitleNoMenu">
          </FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE">
            </FieldRef>
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="AddNewAnnouncement" Location="Resource(wss,addnewitem)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_ONET_HOME)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
      </View>
      <View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="AllItems.aspx">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle" DisplayName="Name">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Surname">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Email">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="ContactNumber">
          </FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="ID">
            </FieldRef>
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
      </View>
    </Views>
    <Forms>
      <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
    </Forms>
  </MetaData>
</List>
```

## Result

---

[image: result:]

as you can see their is still a trail of title left in the view. does anyone know how to change this in my list definition ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to change the display name of the Title is going to be an uphill struggle: There are several versions of the same column, each with their own DisplayName (some of which are created in the list).

If you open your list in SharePoint Manager, you'll see the various hidden Title fields.

My advice would be to hide the title field (`Hidden="TRUE"` in the Content Type, and remove the `FieldRef` from the view) and create/use a different column for the person's first name.

Comment: ye thats what i have been doing... the biggest issue is, their seems to be a bug with Dataview because even though Title is hidden and not required it wont allow you to save your, update because title is missing data :/... perhaps if i made every reference to title field hidden it would fix this

Comment: Alternatively you can set the title to optional by using `Required="FALSE"` in your content type.

Comment: ye ill try a couple more things next time i have this requirements.:)

Answer (score 0):

In the Schema.xml file of the list instance, where you define your view you can set this.

```
 <View ...>
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <ViewFields>
       <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle" DisplayName="Name"></FieldRef>
       ...
    </ViewFields>
    ...
 </View>
```

Comment: if you look at line 35 in the list schema definition i already tried that

Comment: I didn't look at your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your own display name for LinkTitle in content type definition in `<Fields>`
like this

```
    <Fields>
      <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle" DisplayName="Item22" Required="TRUE" Sealed="TRUE"/>
    </Fields>
```

Comment: That has been done in my content type alreday

Comment: Ou not in content, I was wrong.. write this piece of code in "List schema definition" it works.

Comment: its in their two it was previously title.. so i have changed it to
 <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="LinkTitle" DisplayName="Name" Required="TRUE" Sealed="TRUE" />

still no success

Comment: Mm.. try my code it works [link](http://pastebin.com/F89K12PK)

Comment: did with the previous comment